# dotnet.timezones.blat returns 404 - file exists - blazor deployment

Tags: blazor

I  am using visual studio 2022, wasm + hosted site project, the default boiler plate.
I am publishing it to iis server and i get the following error.

[image]

I am clueless as why such an error is occuring. I can see the file doenet.timezones.blat in the framework folder but unable to browse in the browser. I get

[image]

Has some one hosted the blazor application in the IIS server manually? I am banging my head with this error and I could not get past it. Kindly help

Comment: does adding `app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();` do the trick?

Comment: The server project program.cs has this app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

Comment: @Venkay did you see identical issue here? https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29433#issuecomment-765674335

Comment: i saw, but there is no solution to it. It says clean the obj folder, bin folder and deploy it again.

Comment: no. this one answers this question dotnet.timezones.blat returns 404

Comment: To be clear, the text from my comment above is auto-generated. This is 100% a duplicate of that one, which is a canonical for this problem. Multiple answers on the target cover MIME types, and the 404 error you mention is merely a downstream symptom of the error message about file integrity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of trying, I found that .blat and .dat extensions were missing in the MIME types so I did the following:

Open the IIS Manager, Click on the machine name(root dir)
Right side click on MIME type and add the following values

[image]

[image]

and voila ! the error disappeared. I really sweated it out, i dont want others to suffer the same frustration i went through!

Comment: Too late buddy, damage has been done but I am glad I found it eventually. :) This should be in the MS docs if you are deploying to IIS.